# BigQuery Client bigquery.listTableData with Filter condition

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am using the below lines of code to fetch the data from Google Bigquery.

```
 public class BQTEST {
        public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
            String datasetName = "mydataset";
            String tableName = "mytable";
            String projectId = "id-gcs";
            String query =
                    "SELECT id, " +
                            "qtr, " +
                            "sales, " +
                            "year " +
                            "FROM `id-gcs.mydataset.mytable` " +
                            "where MOD(id,2) = 0";
            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId)
                    .setCredentials(
                            ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new
                                    FileInputStream("gcs.json"))
                    )
                    .build().getService();
            TableId tableId = TableId.of(projectId, datasetName, tableName);
            QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration
                    .newBuilder(query)
                    .setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.BATCH)
                    .build();
            try {
                bigquery.query(queryConfig);
    
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
            }
            TableResult results = bigquery.listTableData(
                    tableId,
                    BigQuery.TableDataListOption.pageSize(1)
            );
    
    
            for (FieldValueList row : results.iterateAll()) {
                System.out.printf(
                        "ID: %s qtr: %s sales: %s year: %s\n", row.get(0).getValue(), row.get(1).getValue(), row.get(2).getValue(), row.get(3).getValue());
            }
        
        }
    }
```

I have 12 records in a source table starting id value from 1,2,3...12. Since I applied Mod on ID the result set should be with the id value as 2,4,6,8,10,12.

Instead, it's returning the whole data as a resultset.

So, the condition in where clause is not applied.

Seeking help on this .

Comment: What do you mean by filter? Is PageSize? Or other filter? Can you show an example that failed? and the error printed by the IDE?

Comment: Since I am not able to add more lines of code, edited my Post. kindly check.

Comment: Does it work on BigQuery console?

Comment: Yes. The query works in BigQuery Console.  "Query complete (0.2 sec elapsed, 312 B processed)
"

Comment: Before executing the variable, could you print the value of the variable “query” and execute it in the BigQuery console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing two unrelated things here: running a query, and *then* attempting to read the rows directly from the source table you just queried.  The reason you're not getting filtered results is you're not reading rows from the query results, you're reading rows directly from the source table.

Upon further review, it looks like this is based on some sample code that's misleading; I'll get that addressed.

A short example that may be more illuminating: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query#bigquery_query-java

Notable, see how the result iterator is returned from `bigquery.query()`.  That's where your filtered results are available, not by iterating against the source table.

Comment: I suspect the source of the confusion may be due to a slightly different sample.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-pagination#bigquery_query_pagination-java demonstrates writing a query's results into a new table, and then reads from that new table rather than query iterator.  The `setDestinationTable()` option in the query config builder is the key difference there.

Comment: Thank for the detailed explanation.  Then is there any possibility to use the conditional clause with bigquery.listTableData, or bigquery.listTableData will always return the entire data set from a given table.

Comment: tabledata.list is not capable of server side filtering.  If you're interested in exploring this route, take a look at the storage read API, which does allow both projection and filtering: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/